# Create panel in tab sheet for vaadin

Tags: vaadin, panel

I already create the tab sheet. The problem is I cannot scroll the page so I can see only half of my page. So I have decided to create Panel inside the tab sheet but every time I insert the Panel source code it always error.

```
public PersonRegistration()
{
    VerticalLayout tab = new VerticalLayout();
    tab.setSizeFull();

    TabSheet tabsheet = new TabSheet();
    tabsheet.addStyleName("center-aligned-tabs");
    addComponent(tabsheet);

    VerticalLayout tab1 = new VerticalLayout();
    tab1.addComponent(new PICConfirm());
    tabsheet.addTab(tab1, "IC Confirmation",null);

    VerticalLayout tab2 = new VerticalLayout();
    tab2.addComponent(new PDemography());
    tabsheet.addTab(tab2, "Demography",null);

    VerticalLayout tab3 = new VerticalLayout();
    tab3.addComponent(new PContact());
    tabsheet.addTab(tab3, "Contact",null);

    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setSizeFull();
    panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
    tab.addComponent(panel);
    tab.setExpandRatio(panel, 1);
}
```

Is it okay to put panel inside the tab sheet?

Comment: It always "error" does mean what?

Comment: you're calling panel.getContent().setSizeundfined() but never have set a component in the first place. if that's not the problem, please add the exact errors/traces/... you get.

Comment: What is the error? And yes, it is okay to put a panel into the tab sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling simply setSizeFull(); // if you are implementing View
 in that method and see if it works.